# Bindable function without event name specified

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

What is the effect of making a function Bindable in flex without specifying event name with it? I have done this in my code and it seems to be working alright without any associated event (however it does generate a warning). If I remove the binding from such functions it will does effect the code and doesnt reflect the changes if the return value from the function changes.

Could someone explain me , how and why such Bindable function work even without any event associated with [Bindable] tag.

Example:

```
<mx:Image id="a" source="{getImage(1)}" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" width="10" height="10" click="finalize(event)" autoLoad="true"/>

[Bindable] private var _ratingSelected:int;

[Bindable]
private function getImage(value:int):String
  {
if (value <= _ratingSelected)
return 'images/hr/applicants/star_icon.png';
else
return 'images/hr/applicants/star_icon_dis.png';
  }
```

If I remove the Bindable tag from getImage function here, the image doesnt properly get updated at  the run time.  Please note that _ratingSelected is Bindable variable here. Even though I don't have any event associated with getImage() function, making it Bindable seems to be working just alright.  Does it automatically detect changes to changes in _ratingSelected variable (which is bindable) and call the getImage function at run time? Kindly enlighten.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't specify an event name in the Binding tag, it uses the event "propertyChange". This means that every time the framework gets a "propertyChange" event from your document, it'll try to update the image source by calling `getImage` again.

Now when the value of `_ratingSelected` is updated, a "propertyChange" event is dispatched internally, which then causes the image to be updated.

Note that this has nothing to do with whether `getImage` actually uses `_ratingSelected` to generate its return value. The only connection between `getImage` and `_ratingSelected` from the data binding framework's point of view is the "propertyChange" event which they both claim to dispatch when their respective values have changed (even though `getImage` never actually dispatches it).